# hash string size

Tags: python, hmac, sha

In python I use the following code to create hash for user passwords:

```
self.password = hmac.new(security_key, raw_password, sha1).hexdigest()
```

Now I'd like to save this value to database. What size must be my database column? 
It seems related to digest_size property, but do not know what object or class has such property. sha1 doesn't have one.

Comment: SHA-1 isn't the best choice for a password hash. It's very fast, and it's believed to be weak (if not yet broken). Best practice is something like [bcrypt](http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/), but if you want to stick to the Python standard library, then `sha256` is better than `sha1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of hmac is dependent on the hashing algorithm it uses. In your case, it uses sha1, which always output a 20-byte long byte string according to RFC2104. Calling hexdigest() turns the byte string into a printable hex format. 1 byte = 2 hex numbers, so the total is 40 hex characters. You can safely set your database column to char(40).

Answer (score 2):

The output of the sha-1 hash function will be 20 characters long.
(According to [RFC2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104.html), referenced by the [hmac python module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html): "...L the byte-length of hash outputs (L=16 for MD5, L=20 for SHA-1).")

You can also verify this by:

```
import hashlib;
H = hashlib.sha1("blahblah");
print(H.digest_size);
```